# Radio button javascript if statement not working

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why my javascript isn't working. I'm trying to display a confirm when a radio button is selected, then select another radio button if the user approves the confirm alert.

```
alertFunction: function () {
    var radio = document.getElementById("radio"); 
    if (radio.checked == true) {
        //select other radio button
        if (confirm('Would you like to select other radio?')) {
            document.getElementById("otherRadio").checked = true;
        } else {
        // Do nothing!
        }
    }
}
```

Heres a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sorr2jzm/1/)

Comment: Works for me, if radio is checked, on page load? https://jsfiddle.net/sorr2jzm/2/

Comment: How can I make it work if the radio is not checked on page load? I want the alert to display only when the user checks the radio.

Comment: Check for error messages on the console tab of the browser development tools. Check if the queries you do (document.getElement...) are returning undefined (i.e. if the elements are present on document)

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.onload` doesn't work, as you set jsfiddle to run that code onload. Testing with console.log inside the onload would have revealed that. Changing the fiddle to run onDomready or nowrap makes it execute the function:

https://jsfiddle.net/sorr2jzm/5/

The function will still only execute onload. Changing `window.onload` to `window.onchange` will give the desired behavior?

EDIT:
listen to any window change: https://jsfiddle.net/sorr2jzm/6/

Use window.load but listen to checkbox change only: https://jsfiddle.net/sorr2jzm/7/